# Newman with AzureDevOps + Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, postman, newman

Good morning everyone

I am trying integrate postman tests with AzureDevops Release pipeline. 
I have two steps:

- First step is to install newman
- Second step is to run collection scripts with *newman run* comand

The second step looks like:

```
try
{
    $testFiles = Get-ChildItem *.postman_collection.json -Recurse
$environmentFile = Get-ChildItem *staging.postman_environment.json -Recurse

Write-Host $testFiles.Count files to test

foreach ($f in $testFiles)
{
   $environment  = $environmentFile[0].FullName

   Write-Host running file $f.FullName
   Write-Host usting environment $environment  


   $collection = $f.FullName
   $resultFile = "Results\" + $f.BaseName + ".xml"

   Write-Host running $collection
   Write-Host will create $resultFile


   $(newman run $collection -e $environment -r junit --reporter-junit-export $resultFile)  
}   

}
catch
{
    Write-Host "Exception occured"
    Write-Host $_
}
```

Above step do not work as expected. In the release log I can see the both messages like:

```
   Write-Host running $collection
   Write-Host will create $resultFile
```

However the line

```
$(newman run $collection -e $environment -r junit --reporter-junit-export $resultFile)
```

is not being executed.

I did the same on my local machine and the command is working. However the bad thing is the try catch block is not working and only I can see as the result is :

```
2019-11-22T15:11:23.8332717Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2019-11-22T15:11:23.8341270Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2019-11-22T15:11:23.8390876Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed]Error detected
2019-11-22T15:11:23.8414283Z ##[debug]Leaving D:\a\_tasks\PowerShell_e213ff0f-5d5c-4791-802d-52ea3e7be1f1\2.151.2\powershell.ps1.
```

Do anyone know how to get real error or had experience with newman testing in AzureDevOps ?

Comment: Try adding before your `newman` command this line:
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
It will not solve the problem, but it should help you catch the error properly.

Comment: Just want to check is it succeed for you to run above script in VSTS now? If still has puzzle about that or below suggestion, don't hesitate to leave comment below:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run those above scripts in VSTS, please remove `$()` in the `newman run` line:

```
newman run $collection -e $environment -r junit --reporter-junit-export $resultFile
```

Then the script can be run very successfully.

I think you have known that for powershell command line, there will no result displayed in the powershell command line interface in the even if the `newman run` command has been ran succeed. So, there will no any directly message displayed in the log to let you know whether it is succeed. To confirm this in VSTS, you could check the agent cache if you are using private agent:

[image]